# Duplicated function in PHP

Tags: php, json, function, timing

So I'm trying to get two UNIX timestamps from a JSON Web File, so I want to perform the same action 2 times (for the 2 different timestamps). The JSON contains 2 timestamps I'm looking to use on my website but I don't know how to get both of them at once. I hope this all makes sense...
This is my code;

```
$epoch_jd = $json["response"]["players"][0]["timecreated"]; //UNIX TIME STAMP
$readepoch_jd = gmdate('Y-m-d H:i:s', $epoch_jd);

$time_jd = strtotime($readepoch_jd);

function humanTiming ($time_jd)
{

    $time_jd = time() - $time_jd;
    $time_jd = ($time_jd<1)? 1 : $time_jd;
    $tokens_jd = array (
        31536000 => 'year',
        2592000 => 'month',
        604800 => 'week',
        86400 => 'day',
        3600 => 'hour',
        60 => 'minute',
        1 => 'second'
    );

    foreach ($tokens_jd as $unit_jd => $text_jd) {
        if ($time_jd < $unit_jd) continue;
        $numberOfUnits_jd = floor($time_jd / $unit_jd);
        return $numberOfUnits_jd.' '.$text_jd.(($numberOfUnits_jd>1)?'s':'');
    }

}
```

Than this is the other code I have.

```
$epoch_ol = $json["response"]["players"][0]["lastlogoff"]; //UNIX TIME STAMP
$readepoch_ol = gmdate('Y-m-d H:i:s', $epoch_ol);

$time_ol = strtotime($readepoch_ol);

function humanTiming ($time_ol)
{

    $time_ol = time() - $time_ol;
    $time_ol = ($time_ol<1)? 1 : $time_ol;
    $tokens_ol = array (
        31536000 => 'year',
        2592000 => 'month',
        604800 => 'week',
        86400 => 'day',
        3600 => 'hour',
        60 => 'minute',
        1 => 'second'
    );

    foreach ($tokens_ol as $unit_ol => $text_ol) {
        if ($time_ol < $unit_ol) continue;
        $numberOfUnits_ol = floor($time_ol / $unit_ol);
        return $numberOfUnits_ol.' '.$text_ol.(($numberOfUnits_ol>1)?'s':'');
    }

}
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Aren't the two functions identical? Why do you need to redefine it?

Comment: The name of the parameter is different, but that doesn't affect how you use the function. Just define it once, and call it from both places.

Comment: Do not fear the DateTime class -- it will not hurt you.  Surely you have researched the many "human-readable time" pages on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just declare your function once, in a non-specific manner:

```
function humanTiming ($time)
{
    $time = time() - $time;
    $time = ($time<1)? 1 : $time;
    $tokens = array (
        31536000 => 'year',
        2592000 => 'month',
        604800 => 'week',
        86400 => 'day',
        3600 => 'hour',
        60 => 'minute',
        1 => 'second'
    );
    foreach ($tokens as $unit => $text) {
        if ($time < $unit) continue;
        $numberOfUnits = floor($time / $unit);
        return $numberOfUnits.' '.$text.(($numberOfUnits>1)?'s':'');
    }
}
```

Then call it twice:

```
$epoch_jd = $json["response"]["players"][0]["timecreated"]; //UNIX TIME STAMP
$readepoch_jd = gmdate('Y-m-d H:i:s', $epoch_jd);
$time_jd = strtotime($readepoch_jd);
echo humanTiming($time_jd);

$epoch_ol = $json["response"]["players"][0]["lastlogoff"]; //UNIX TIME STAMP
$readepoch_ol = gmdate('Y-m-d H:i:s', $epoch_ol);
$time_ol = strtotime($readepoch_ol);
echo humanTiming($time_ol);
```

Comment: No, it's perfect thank you, I'm only new to functions :) Thanks Nick

Comment: That's great. Glad to be of help.